# Google maps embed minimum size requirement?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

I currently have the iframe size set to 190px x 190px.  Is there a minimum size that google will not display the map to?  Is there a maximum of maps per page that google will not show maps for?

Example [here](http://mgoode.com/index.php?option=com_mls&view=list).  The code is there, it just doesn't display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the javascript console?  I see errors that look like they explain the problem:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getElements' /index.php?option=com_mls&view=list (1):1
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getProperty' /index.php?option=com_mls&view=list (1):1
>
> 16 Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

Looks like you are trying to put a google map inside an iframe, rather than using the embedded code they provide.

> Paste HTML to embed in website

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=719+NORTH+CHARLES++BELLEVILLE&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=719+N+Charles+St,+Belleville,+St+Clair,+Illinois+62220&amp;t=h&amp;z=14&amp;ll=38.521293,-89.978031&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=719+NORTH+CHARLES++BELLEVILLE&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=719+N+Charles+St,+Belleville,+St+Clair,+Illinois+62220&amp;t=h&amp;z=14&amp;ll=38.521293,-89.978031&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

Comment: Yeah, I took out a bunch of stuff in the URL when I got the code from google maps.